# jQuery function undefined in IE11

Tags: jquery, function, internet-explorer

I have a master file (script.js) with `$.getscript` commands connecting all the set of scripts. This file is being loaded in the following manner:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8;IE=edge;chrome=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>      
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/contextmenu/dist/jquery.ui.position.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
```

The master file loads scripts in the following order:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getScript( "SITENAME/js/general.js", function(){});
    $.getScript( "SITENAME/js/admin.js", function(){});
    $.getScript( "SITENAME/js/building.js", function(){});
    $.getScript( "SITENAME/js/fight.js", function(){});
    $.getScript( "SITENAME/js/items.js", function(){});
    $.getScript( "SITENAME/js/locations.js", function(){});
    $.getScript( "SITENAME/js/stats.js", function(){});
    $.getScript( "SITENAME/js/trade.js", function(){});
    $.getScript( "SITENAME/js/bots.js", function(){});
    $.getScript( "SITENAME/js/chat.js", function(){});  
});
```

Almost all the scripts are activated with `$(document).ready()` except of general.js that contains main functions that are being used by other scripts. There are no conditions of loading like `$(document).ready()`, just plain functions declarations, like:

```
function getData( val ){ 
    return $.when(
        $.ajax('SITENAME/ajax.php', {
            data: val,
            type: 'POST'
        })
    );
}
```

Everything works totally fine in Chrome and FF but not in IE. When I try to call `getData()` from fight.js IE throws SCRIPT5009 error "getData is undefined".

I know for sure that general.js is being loaded (I used `alert('loaded')` test for that in general.js). I tried to load it explicitly via `<script>` tag but that did not work either.

Why does IE not see the functions from that file?